# How to verify PPTP service is configured properly and is serving correctly?

Tags: 16.04, vpn, pptpd

I am trying to set up a PPTP server on my VPS running Ubuntu 16.04. I have followed all the steps as detailed in the below two links:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PPTPServer
https://bobcares.com/blog/install-pptp-server-ubuntu/

However, I cannot VPN to my VPS neither from Windows 10, nor Ubunto 22.04, nor Android.

I am pretty experienced in System Administration though I am not good at networking, to be honest.

I need to take steps to pinpoint the problem.

The pptpd service seems functioning pretty well.

```
mike@vpsXXX:~$ netstat -ntl
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1723            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1822            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::1822                 :::*                    LISTEN
mike@vpsXXX:~$ sudo service pptpd status
[sudo] password for mike:
● pptpd.service - PoPToP Point to Point Tunneling Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/pptpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2023-07-08 09:22:42 EDT; 5h 56min ago
 Main PID: 20218 (pptpd)
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 156.0K
      CPU: 12ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/pptpd.service
           └─20218 /usr/sbin/pptpd --fg

Jul 08 13:48:07 vpsXXX pptpd[20808]: CTRL: Client 198.199.93.96 control connection started
Jul 08 15:02:19 vpsXXX pptpd[20218]: MGR: dropped slow initial connection
Jul 08 15:04:20 vpsXXX pptpd[20218]: MGR: dropped slow initial connection
Jul 08 15:06:21 vpsXXX pptpd[20218]: MGR: dropped slow initial connection
Jul 08 15:08:21 vpsXXX pptpd[20218]: MGR: dropped slow initial connection
Jul 08 15:10:22 vpsXXX pptpd[20218]: MGR: dropped slow initial connection
Jul 08 15:12:23 vpsXXX pptpd[20218]: MGR: dropped slow initial connection
Jul 08 15:14:24 vpsXXX pptpd[20218]: MGR: dropped slow initial connection
Jul 08 15:16:24 vpsXXX pptpd[20218]: MGR: dropped slow initial connection
Jul 08 15:18:25 vpsXXX pptpd[20218]: MGR: dropped slow initial connection
mike@vpsXXX:~$
```

I need to take steps to pinpoint the problem. Any comment/clue is much appreciated.

I came across this [How to fix MGR: dropped slow initial connection with pptpd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1444233/how-to-fix-mgr-dropped-slow-initial-connection-with-pptpd) which seems relevant since I get the same warnings as check the pptpd's status.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are trying to set up a VPN, Open Connect is a better alternative working for Iran for now. It comes both with a mobile app and a desktop client. It also offers user management where you can add, delete, lock, and unlock users.

Just google **How to Set Up the OpenConnect VPN Server** to find good tutorials.  There are plenty out there online.